# What's wrong with this grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

$L = \{ w : w  \in \{a, b\}^* \land |w|_a = |w|_b\}$ where $|w|_a$ means number of $a$ in string $w$.

I came up with this grammar:

$S \rightarrow aSb \ |\ bSa \ | \ \epsilon .$

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the string $w= abba $.
$w$ clearly belongs to $L$ as $|a|=|b|$ but there's no derivation which allows you to generate $w$ given your CFG.

In practice, your rules only deal with the imbalance in the number of $a$'s and $b$'s.
 You need to make sure to generate every string $w \in (a+b)^*$ with the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

A CFG grammar for your language can be the following:

$S \rightarrow \epsilon\ |\ aSbS \ | \ bSaS $